# Why does my Rails App work after I disabled the Virtual Host? (Phusion Passenger + Apache2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

today I installed a new Home Server and setup a Ruby on Rails and Server environment.
I used [this](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_installation)
guide to get things started with Phusion Passenger (all exact the same(besides the ServerName)).

After I enabled the Virtual Host and restarted Apache2, none of my routes would work, only the Files in my public rails folder. I googled for a solution but found nothing, what would have helped me.

So, after a while, I just gave up and disabled my Virtual Host again. But than, when i visited my Site again, the Routes were all okay. Even though the Virtual Host shouldn't point to the Rails App anymore (I'm new to Apache2s Virtual Host, so i don't quite understand them).

Now my question is, why does it all work? And why does the URL still point to my Rails App? I want to understand it, so that I can reproduce the steps when needed. Hopefully I expressed myself well enough.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing the files listed it sounds like you have options indexes enabled some where.  Try grepping through /etc/httpd/mods-enabled for options indexes.

```
<Directory /path/to/directory>
  Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

As for why it's working after deleting your virtual host.  I would suggest looking through the other mods enabled.  There may have been a conflicting virtual host.